# MySql Event Creation For Schedule Task

Tags: mysql

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
    EVENT IF NOT EXISTS RESET_RUNNING
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 day
    STARTS CURRENT_TIME()
    ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
    DO BEGIN
    UPDATE APIS SET algo_status="not running"
    WHERE algo_status="running";
    
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

on running this code i am receving
Error Code: 1105. syntax error at position 14 near 'EVENT'
Can someone help me

Trying to create an schedule task at every day at 12 am

Comment: *syntax error at position 14 near 'EVENT'* - this is **NOT** MySQL error message...

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error https://dbfiddle.uk/ZvjzxGH2 (nb fiddle does not require delimiters) I do get an error in fiddle if I set delimiters. Where are you running the code - in a ui for example mysqlworkbench ? from command line or something else?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for creating an event in MySQL looks correct, but it may be that the version of MySQL you are using does not support events.

To check if your version of MySQL supports events, you can run the following command:

SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'event_scheduler';

If the value of the event_scheduler variable is ON, then events are supported. If it is OFF, you can enable it by running:

SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON

Comment: Thanks this is a problem of PlanetScale Database